# Django - Get values from ManyToManyField which is foreing key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to understand.

I have the next models :

```
class TagsList(models.Model):
    tags_list = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tags_list

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(TagsList)
```

how i can get related tags by object (in my case object with `post_id`)?
It's my view file :

```
def single(request, post_id):
    object_post = Blog.objects.get(id=post_id)
    tags = TagsList.objects.all()
    content = {
        'object_post': object_post,
        'tags': tags,
    }
    return render(request, 'single.html', content)
```

I tried all cases, but how to include to content exactly tags which are related to this object, don't know.
Thanks all, for the help.

P.S. Using django 1.11

Comment: try `tags=object_post.tags.all()` in def single.

Comment: OMG
why i'm so stupid?)
i tried it but make some miss)
it's working
tags_1=object_post.tags.all().values()

Answer (score 2):

*initial answer from comments*:

In a many-to-many relation you can access the related objects, try this in `def single`:

```
tags=object_post.tags.all()
```